# framework for java as .NET is ther for c#

Tags: c#, java, .net

As .NET is framework for c# is there any framework for java? I mean whenever people talks about c#, .NET will be involved in that discussion but in case of java i didnt find as such.

Comment: reason for downvote. why dont people give reason for downvote, its a kind of feedback.

Comment: Probably for hard to understand grammar and spelling mistakes. (note I wasn't the one that downvoted)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the question is ambiguous and "framework" is left undefined, so we can only guess what "framework" means to you.  Depending on definition, java has hundreds of "frameworks" available.

Comment: I think the question is very clear, and not being a native english speaker doesn't warrant a downvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java is already both a platform and a language. So there are [standard libraries](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) which come with J2SE (and other editions). It's slightly clearer in the .NET world, although people still regularly say C# when they mean .NET or vice versa :(

Oh, and JVM (Java Virtual Machine) ~= CLR (Common Language Runtime)

.NET was basically designed with multiple languages in mind, whereas the whole Java platform was designed to run Java; the fact that there are umpteen other languages running on it now (Scala, Groovy, Jython etc) is purely coincidental :)

Comment: Although arguably the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) is the execution framework - java is just a language that compiles down to JVM compatible bytecode. 

.Net has always had a more ingrained distinction though as it has been multi-language from the beginning

Comment: @saret: The JVM isn't a framework - it's a VM. You need libraries to work with it before it becomes a framework, IMO.

Comment: sorry didn't actually read the question properly, seems a little bit worded incorrectly. ".NET is framework for c#" - .Net is a bit all encompassing in this statement as this could include the BCL/JIT/CTS/CLR etc... what is Framework being refered to as here...?

Comment: @saret, question seems to be asking about a "Framework Class Library"

Answer (score 7):

The [Java Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) is the framework for the [Java programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)).

Comment: Might want to link to the latest version, 1.6: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/